# JMeter - Pass a file as a part of a body parameter

Tags: jmeter, postman

In my postman I pass through a file as a body parameter like so:

[image]

How to replicate this in JMeter through a HTTP Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See JMeter 5's [changes](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html):

> It is now also possible to send a JSON Body with attached file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **recording** the request in Postman using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

1. Create a recording test plan using JMeter Templates feature

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image: JMeter Templates Recording]
2. Prepare Postman for recording.

   - From Postman main menu choose `File -> Settings -> Proxy`
   - Set proxy port to `8888` and proxy host to where your JMeter is running

   [image: JMeter Postman Record Request]
3. Copy your `1mbfile.csv` to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation (this is required so JMeter could locate the file and properly build the request, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details)
4. Execute the request in Postman
5. JMeter will capture the request under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)